# Proof that connectedness is not relative to the set studied / Connectedness absolute notion

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

In the same vein as in theorem $2.33$ in Rudin's PMA book (where he proves that compactness is absolute), I am trying to prove that connectedness is also an absolute notion.

That is to say that if $Y\subseteq X$ and $E\subseteq Y$ then $E$ is connected relatively to $Y$ if and only if it is connected relatively to $X$.

So I started writing the definitions (trying to prove $E$ not connected in $X$, if and only if, $E$ not connected in $Y$)
:

> E is not connected in $Y$ if $\exists A$ ,$B$ such as:
>
> - $A$, $B$ are open in Y
> - $A$, $B$ $\ne \emptyset$
> - $A\cap B = \emptyset$
> - $A\cup B = E$

and:

> E is not connected in $X$ if $\exists A$ ,$B$ such as:
>
> - $A$, $B$ are open in X
> - $A$, $B$ $\ne \emptyset$
> - $A\cap B = \emptyset$
> - $A\cup B = E$

. However I've got a problem with the second definition: how can $E$ be equal to $A\cup B$ with $A$ and $B$ open in $X$ ? If $Y=\mathbb R$ and $X=\mathbb R^2$ then, for an open set $V$ of $X$,  we must have necessarily $V \cap Y^c \ne \emptyset$. But then, $E=A\cup B$ (with $A$ open in $X$ and $B$ open in $X$) would imply that $E\nsubseteq Y$. Which contradicts the assumptions !

Comment: In last line of definition (in both cases), it should be $E \subseteq A \cup B$ - we need $A \cup B$ to cover $E$, it's ok if it will have also some points not in $E$.

Comment: Yes, and better prove that $E$ is not connected in $X$ iff it is not connected in *itself*.

Comment: I'm sorry but the definitions I've seen so far are with E=A∪B
. I like to stick to the definitions (since I am not very intuitive)

Comment: If you have seen  E=A∪B, it must be that A,B are open subsets not of X but of E (with the induced topology from X, i.e. $A=U\cap E,B=V\cap E$ where U,V are open subsets of X).

Comment: Yes, that's what I've been thinking since I read mihaild's comment. They must be subsets of $E$ (so $E\subseteq A \cup B$ is the general definition, and the definitions I've seen with $E= A\cup B$ are particular cases). However I'm still looking for a website (or source, or book) that provides the definition with $E\subseteq A\cup B$.

Comment: If I accept the link you provided ("does this answer you question") does it close my question ?

Comment: @nobium No, this does not close your  question. But we can close it as a duplicate.